# Can a Hindu eat with a non Hindu?

Tags: caste-system, food, untouchability

In a video by the Sikh Jagraj Singh, Hinduism was discussed in relation to a passage from the Guru Granth Sahib.

In the GGS, the Guru Nanak described the Hindus as hypocrites for eating with Muslims as he claims that according to Hinduism the Muslims and indeed all non Hindus are untouchables and should not be eaten with.

Therefore, my question is this: Can a Hindu eat with a non Hindu and are those non Hindus classed as Dalit?

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=HdrS2p5AFJ8

Point at 4:50

Comment: Can you please share the link to that video as well. Thanks. Guru Nanak himself was a Hindu by birth so not sure what you say is correct. Also Sikhs are known for organizing langars where every one can come and have food irrespective of their religion or caste hence it is opposite to what is stated above.

Comment: @Just_Do_I thttps://m.youtube.com/watch?v=HdrS2p5AFJ8 watch from 4:50. Yes I'm well aware of the Sikh teachings but I'm not talking about Sikhism I'm talking about Hinduism

Comment: I am not aware of all Hindus but orthodox Hindu bramhanas (especially those who still follow certain vedic rituals to this day) eat only with fellow bramhanas, are served only by brahmana men/women and only eat food prepared by bramahanas or themselves. Non-bramahanas do not hover around the vicinity. Nor "impure" bramhanas.

Comment: See if [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24658/2995) answers your question.

Comment: @sv. Whilst interesting, it doesn't answer the question

Comment: @Charlie if you consider non-Hindu to be a [Mleccha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mleccha), then yes, a Hindu shouldn't be interacting with them. Forget sitting and having a drink together. However, no modern Hindu considers a foreigner or person of different faith, a Mleccha. So that's why you see Hindus mingling with people of other religions nowadays. So the statement "according to Hinduism the Muslims and indeed all non Hindus are untouchables and should not be eaten with" might have been true at some point in history but not anymore. So, answer to the question in title is yes/no/maybe.

Comment: @sv. So what you're saying is that it is true that they can't eat with non Hindus but people refuse to follow the teachings? Seems Guru Nanak had a point

Comment: @Charlie The same texts that prohibit interacting with Dalits also prohibit interacting with Non-Hindus, and Nanak mocked those who refused to interact with Dalits but interacted with Muslims. This criticism doesn't apply to those who are willing to interact with both Dalits and Non-Hindus.