# Is there any verse in the Vedas that talks about foreigners or foreign land?

Tags: vedas, upanishads

Is there any verse in the Vedas or upanishades that talks about foreigners or foreign land, language, customs.

Comment: The following answer might be helpful: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20394/4732

Comment: @Rickross thank you it was very helpful